# Filtering the next 2 weeks lookahead after another date

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is showing a weird error, shown in the screenshot
[image]

I need to click Ok for the filter to work

```
Sub LA2w()
Dim range_to_filter As Range
Set range_to_filter = Range("K6:S999")
Dim DD As Range
Set DD = Cells(1, 11)


range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=Array("In Progress", "Not Started", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlAnd
range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & DD.Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & DD.Value + 15


End Sub
```

The revised one that @BigBen suggested is

```
Sub LA4W()
Dim range_to_filter As Range
Set range_to_filter = Range("K6:S999")
Dim DD As Range
Set DD = Cells(1, 11)


range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=Array("In Progress", "Not Started", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlAnd
range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & Format$(DD.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Format(DD.Value + 30, "mm/dd/yyyy")


End Sub
```

I attached the sheet in here in case you want to see it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lMkZ6nwaDxMYS3gVUH5ypGsBFIWt3JfZ/view?usp=sharing

It has the macro in it, suprisingly, it worked perfect in this "test.xlsm"
But when i go back to my project file, it says compile error

[image]

Comment: `Set` is used for object variables. The `.Value` of a cell is not an object.

Comment: thanks @BigBen , what shall i use instead? String?

Comment: Regarding your edit: One of your modules is named `Format`. It would be best to change that name since it shadows the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function. If changing the name is not an option, then in your code snippet, put a `VBA.` before `Format$`.

Comment: @BigBen changed the name and it worked like a charm. thanks for the genuis tip (to me at least:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is for object variables. So `Set DD` to the *range*, then use its value in the autofilter criteria.

```
Dim DD As Range
Set DD = Cells(11, 1)

range_to_filter.AutoFilter _
   Field:=11, _
   Criteria1:=">=" & Format$(DD.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"), _
   Operator:=xlAnd, _
   Criteria2:="<=" & Format$(DD.Value + 15, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Another (potentially clearer) option: a `Date` variable:

```
Dim DD As Date
DD = Cells(11, 1).Value

range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & DD, _
                        Operator:=xlAnd, _
                        Criteria2:="<=" & DD + 15
```

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, the 1st one worked. 
but with a weird "error" or whatever it's called.

the filter was applied, but it wasn't really filtering.
I had to go to the filter, click on "Custom filter",
there I can see the correct dates that we applied into the range
all I have to do is to click "ok", and then the filter is applied.
It's wierd that i have to go through these steps just to click ok

Comment: Hmm. Is the value in cell A11 entered manually, is it a formula, or something else?

Comment: yes the date in A11 is entered manually

Comment: Does it work if you use `Criteria1:=">=" & Format$(DD.Value,"mm/dd/yyyy")` and `Criteria2:="<=" & Format$(DD.Value + 15,"mm/dd/yyyy")`?

Comment: it highlights "Criteria2" and says "Expected: end of statement"